# How to put an id on the sSearch of DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Here is my sample DataTable :

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "oLanguage"  : {
        "sSearch" : "Search all columns",
        "sInfoFiltered" : ""
    },
    "And some many more.." : ".."
});
```

I want to have the sSearch input have an id for itself so I can target it in jQuery.

When i `inspect element` it : `<input type="search" class="" aria-controls="">`

I can target it indirectly through the div that contains it, but I want it precise.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RS94H/52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ID to element in `fnDrawCallback` function.

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
"oLanguage"  : {
    "sSearch" : "Search all columns",
    "sInfoFiltered" : ""
},
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
   $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("id", "sSearch");
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5wqjucj/)**